# Adding data label in D3 Line chart (for Power BI)

Tags: d3.js, powerbi

Whole source code can be found [here](https://github.com/fredrikheden/PowerBI-visuals/blob/master/src/Clients/Visuals/visuals/kpiStatusWithHistory.ts).

Requirement: I need to add Data Labels to the Line chart (aka above to the circles)

Attempt: Added

```
selectionCircle.append("text")
                    .attr(function (d) { return d.x; })
                    .attr(function (d) { return d.y; })
```

Below the line

```
var selectionCircle = this.sMainGroupElement2.selectAll("circle").data(dataPoints, function (d) { return d.dataId; });
```

Tried adding my code at various places in the original code but not working.

Comment: see for displayName in the power bi.it may be the one you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following code below the existing "selectionCircle.exit().remove();" line:

```
this.sMainGroupElement2.selectAll("text").remove();
var selectionLabel = this.sMainGroupElement2.selectAll("circleLabel").data(dataPoints, function (d) { return d.dataId; });
selectionLabel.enter()
    .append("text")
    .classed(".circleLabel", true)
    .text(function(d) { return d.ActualOrg; })
    .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y-sH*0.05; })
    .attr("fill", "#bebebe")
    .attr("style", "font-family:calibri;font-size:" + sL * 0.04 + "px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")                    
selectionLabel.exit().remove();
```

It not best-pratice to remove (they should be updated instead) all elements like the first line does, but it will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really knowledgeable with Power BI, but in d3.js you would just append the text nodes in the enter statement, just like you appended the circle.

So it would look something like this:

```
selectionCircle.enter()
    .append("circle")
        .classed(".circle112", true)
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("r", sH * 0.02)
        .attr("fill", statusColor)
        .attr("stroke", "white")
        .attr("stroke-width", sH * 0.015)
    .append("text")
        .text('some label text can also be a function') //Change this
        .attr(function (d) { return d.x; })
        .attr(function (d) { return d.y; });
```

The [.enter()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#enter) method of d3 iterates through the data and is used to add new elements depending on the data.

Hope this helps.